# how to get 3 array before that array in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have been fighting with this all day and would like another set of eyes to maybe give me some insight. I'm not sure I am even approaching this the correct way.i have an array like this.

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => 1352
  1 => 746
  2 => 593
  3 => 542
  4 => 522
]
```

how do I display 3 arrays before the index of the array and if the index of the array is 0,1,2 it will display 0 I hope the result is like this

```
$result = array(
    [0] = array(
        0 => 0
    )

    [1] = array(
        0 => 0
    )

    [2] = array(
        0 => 0
    )

   [3] = array(
        0 => 1352
        1 => 746
        2 => 593
    )

   [4] = array(
         0 => 746
         1 => 593
         2 => 542
    )
    ....
)
```

thank u :)

Comment: Please read this utorial before posting your quesiton https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand the logic behind the expected results, but this will give you the one from your example

```
$result = [0 => [ 0 => 0], 1 => [ 0 => 0], 2 => [ 0 => 0]];
foreach($startingArray as $key => $value) {
    if ($key + 1 > 2) $result[$key +1][] = $value;
    if ($key + 2 > 2) $result[$key +2][] = $value;
    if ($key + 3 > 2) $result[$key +3][] = $value;
}
```

[Here is a running example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a9405c28cb30532dcf9fc37af0d1f498c1fa37cf)

Comment: The results of the data displayed in 3 will be summed up later

Comment: @salman ok. does it answer your question ?

Comment: yes thank u for your answare and solution :D